# How to remove navigation bar on eBay?

Tags: html, css, ebay-api

I am trying to create a custom product page http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Que-Modular-Shotgun-Microphone-Kit-/271032405588?pt=UK_Music_Instruments_Microphones_MJ&hash=item3f1aca4e54#ht_2243wt_971 on eBay, but am having trouble removing the navigation bar and header bar.

In the display settings for the left navigation bar, I have unticked all of the boxes, but the Categories list is still appearing, and I cannot remove it.

Here is an example of a product page without the left-navigation and header http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/2009-ROYAL-MINT-FIRST-YEAR-ISSUE-GOLD-PROOF-QUARTER-SOVEREIGN-COIN-BOX-COA-/400288750395?pt=Coins_BritishProofs_RL&hash=item5d33119b3b#ht_2655wt_1190 so you can see what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Surely, eBay will penalize you for this at some point in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add jquery to your page you can do this command and it'll be removed from the page:

`jQuery(".tb-cw").find('table:eq(5)').find('td:first').remove()`

Comment: Thanks @Luke, does that not violate Ebays terms and conditions? Do you have an example of how it should be added to the page, as I've read that you are not allowed to src Javascript codes into ebay product pages. Thanks again for all your help, really appreciate it!

Comment: Just a quick update, it appears the issue I was having was down to the fact that by "Listing frame" settings were set to display the header and left navigation, and they overrode the settings I mentioned in my original post.
I didn't try out the jQuery solution, but thanks @Luke all the same!

Comment: I find it hard to believe that one could get away with doing this for very long.  I suspect eBay will catch on and penalize you in some fashion.